# How can i get no-form data from a row of a table (looped) , using AJax to be able to update a column(by <select>) in flask and jinja

Tags: ajax, flask, post, select

I'm using flask and jinja on a page to loop through a database table to display a table, while i want to be able to set 1 column of the rows editable by making a dropdown  form (looping from another db table).

while i can use Ajax and onchange to get the newly selected form data to send to the backend function, but i cant get the row id that i need ( which is not part of the form) , to query the database to update the row with the data.

Ajax part:

```
     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.staff-title').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/admin/manage-position',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response){
              console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error){
              console.log(error)
        }

      });

    });
});
</script>
```

html page part:

```
          {% for staff in all_staff: %}
         {% if staff.title.id != 1 %}
        <tr>
          <th>{{ staff.id }}</th>
          <td>{{ staff.first_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ staff.last_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ staff.email }}</td>
          <form >
              <td>
                 <select style="margin:-5px;padding:7px" class="staff-title" name="position_id" >
                     <option value ='{{staff.title.id}}' selected >
                         {{ staff.title.title }}</option>
                 {% for position in all_positions %}
                     <option class="newly-selected" value ='{{position.id}}' id="{{position.id}}"> {{ position.title }}</option>
                 {% endfor %}

                 </select>
              </td>
          </form>
        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

and backend part:

```
    if request.method =="POST":

    new_position_id = request.form.get('position_id')

    update_user = User.query.filter_by(id= "How can i get the id from the row ?" ).first()
    update_user.position_id = new_position_id
    db.session.commit()
```

OR is there a better or more elegant way to achive this?

[image: This is the idea]

Comment: I kinda tested something, I added an extra value ( staff.id ).     to the <option class="newly-selected" value ='{{[position.id, staff.id]}}' id="{{position.id}}"> {{ position.title }}</option>

then did this :    position_id = request.form.get('position_id').strip('[]').replace(", ",'')
then loop two number into a list. haven't gone any further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest("tr").find("th").text()` to get `id` column value where select-box has been change then use `$(this).serialize() + "&id=" + row_id` to pass this as well to your backend page.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.staff-title').change(function() {
    //get row id..
    var row_id = $(this).closest("tr").find("th").text().trim();
    console.log("row_id", row_id)
    console.log($(this).serialize() + "&id=" + row_id)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/admin/manage-position',
      data: $(this).serialize() + "&id=" + row_id, //pass same access it using `id`
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      },
      error: function(error) {
        //console.log(error)
      }

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>SW</td>
    <td>Yu</td>
    <td>swyu@something</td>
    <form>
      <td>
        <select style="margin:-5px;padding:7px" class="staff-title" name="position_id">
          <option value='1' selected>
            Soemthings</option>

          <option class="newly-selected" value='1' id="1"> A</option>
          <option class="newly-selected" value='2' id="2"> B</option>


        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>SWA</td>
    <td>YuT</td>
    <td>swyu4@something</td>
    <form>
      <td>
        <select style="margin:-5px;padding:7px" class="staff-title" name="position_id">
          <option value='1' selected>
            Soemthings</option>

          <option class="newly-selected" value='1' id="1"> A</option>
          <option class="newly-selected" value='2' id="2"> B</option>


        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ohhhh nice...thanks!!!   Would this get the primary key id of the data or the id of the row in html?

Comment: This `{{ staff.id }}` value it will get . You need that value only or some other value ? .

Comment: YES!! that's exactly what it's needed! thanks! let me try it out :)

Comment: YOU are a genius! side question : How do you guys get sooo good at parsing or extracting data? and tips for improvement? cheeers!

Comment: Just learning on stackoverflow . I recommend you to go through documentation for jquery and [tree traversal topic](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)